# I can't get a Modal Window to work! I tried every tutorial I can find

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, asp.net-ajax

I've followed all tutorials exactly (or so I think) and I can't get a modal window to open. Right now, I'm just trying to get one to open in a "test" ASP page, so I can figure out the functionality.

Here is my code for "Test.aspx"

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false"  CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %> 
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>

<act:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server"
   TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
   PopupControlID="Panel1"
   OkControlID="OkButton"
   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></act:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="ModalWindow">
   <asp:Table Width="100%" runat="server">
   <asp:TableRow>
       <asp:TableCell>
          Fields1:
       </asp:TableCell>
       <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtFields1" runat="server">
                   </asp:TextBox>    
       </asp:TableCell>
   </asp:TableRow>
   </asp:Table>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
       <asp:Button ID="btnCancel3" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
   </asp:Panel>

   <asp:Button ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Link Button" />
```

I also put this at the top of Site.Master

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

The error I am getting is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gCvF.png

If I click to ignore the error, this is what happens
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0f1k.png

Comment: You've got the TagPrefix alias for AjaxControlToolkit set to "cc1", but, in your markup, you've prefixed the `ModalPopupExtender` with "act".  That might be causing some problems.

Comment: Also, when do you get that error?  When you click on `LinkButton`?

Comment: Yup, I was mixing up the TagPrefix, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OkControlID="OkButton"`

should match the submit button

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />`

To close the modal window. You currently don't have a button with the ID "OkButton"

**EDIT:**
Also, you want to use

`<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" > </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>`

instead of

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">    </asp:ScriptManager>`

(or in your case I think you want to use `<act:ToolkitScriptManager...` but I'm not a pro so play with it)

Note: I figured this out a few days ago, and I had to add the attribute `CombineScripts="false"` to the `ToolkitScriptManager` to get it to work, but I think this depends on your environment and what other javascript files you have running

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! I guess I was mixing myself up a lot with multiple tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEllinger In case you don't know what Steve is talking about regarding "accepting" his answer, see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)